# How to get the objectName of MDI Area subwindow?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qmdiarea

I have tried

```
self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow().objectName
self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow().objectName()
```

But neither of them gave me the object name I set:

```
self.subwindow.setObjectName("subwindow_1")
```

Any advice? Thanks a lot. Full testing code is attached:

```
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(687, 438)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 531, 381))
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.subwindow.setObjectName("subwindow_test_the_object_name")
        self.Add = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Add.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 121, 23))
        self.Add.setObjectName("Add")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 687, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)       
        self.Add.clicked.connect(self.Add_window) # connect the button to Add_window function
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def Add_window(self):   
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        print("there is a subwindow activated")
        self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow()
        self.subwindow.show()
        Act_window=self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow()
        print("this is subwindow 1 "+str(Act_window.objectName()))
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.subwindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Subwindow"))
        self.Add.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Window"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is a very simple sample with objectName() does not work with subwindow but it works with button and the parent MDIarea, my goal is to get the active subwindow object name such as subwindow_test_the_object_name in this case, if I have multiple subwindows with different object name, I can grab this object name as a signal. Thanks.

Comment: `self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow().objectName()` is correct in principle. If you still have problems, add a [mcve], please.

Comment: @FJSevilla Thanks a lot for your comment, and I have attached a simple sample, it seems the objectName() does not work well with the MDIarea subwindow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following instruction:

```
self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.subwindow.setObjectName("subwindow_test_the_object_name")
```

you are giving a name to the widget that is going to be inside the `QMdiSubWindow`, not the `QMdiSubWindow`, so if you want to retrieve the name of that element you must use the `widget()` method of QMdiSubWindow:

```
def Add_window(self):   
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
    print("there is a subwindow activated")
    self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow()
    self.subwindow.show()
    Act_window =self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow()
    print("this is subwindow 1 "+str(Act_window.widget().objectName()))
```

Output:

```
there is a subwindow activated
this is subwindow 1 subwindow_test_the_object_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eyllanesc, It works now, did not know need call one more .widget() to get it.

Comment: When I use mpl_toolbar to control two plot window under MDI subwindows sometimes it shows "already locked" any adive on this, thanks.

Comment: @Tom If you have any questions, create a question.